# Clear relation between Android version, API level, NDK version and platform version?

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-version, android-api-levels

I'm new to Android system, and trying to port some legacy C++ work to Android 5.1 system. I'm a bit confused on version number which I met each day.

I search the StackOverflow, and found below to link are helpful, but still a bit confusion.

There's direct mapping between Android and API level. See this good link:
[Android: API level VS. Android version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8629687/android-api-level-vs-android-version)

However, when I decide to pick up NDK version to build my native application. I found I was confused. Even this link [Relation between the NDK version and the Android version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33468849/relation-between-the-ndk-version-and-the-android-version) give some information on version relation, but, it still seems too much choice for me. Take NDK-r10 as example, in its platform directory,  there are list of different version toolchain.

```
2018-07-10  12:32    <DIR>          android-12
2018-07-10  12:31    <DIR>          android-13
2018-07-10  12:31    <DIR>          android-14
2018-07-10  12:32    <DIR>          android-15
2018-07-10  12:31    <DIR>          android-16
2018-07-10  12:32    <DIR>          android-17
2018-07-10  12:31    <DIR>          android-18
2018-07-10  12:31    <DIR>          android-19
2018-07-10  12:33    <DIR>          android-21
2018-07-10  12:33    <DIR>          android-3
2018-07-10  12:31    <DIR>          android-4
2018-07-10  12:30    <DIR>          android-5
2018-07-10  12:33    <DIR>          android-8
2018-07-10  12:33    <DIR>          android-9
```

Does this platform version have relationship with API level? Is there some risk I pick up the latest NDK and latest platform version to build application for a older Android system? I was confused on that.

Could someone point out the right way to follow ?

Thanks very much!

Jeff

Comment: From [the NDK documentation](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/application_mk): _"This [is] the minimum Android platform version you want to support. For example, a value of **android-15** specifies that your library uses APIs that are not available below Android 4.0.3 (API level 15) and can't be used on devices running a lower platform version."_

Comment: As for which NDK version you should use, this is what one of the NDK maintainers has to say: _"The NDK version and the Android version you are targeting are orthogonal concepts. You should always be using the latest NDK for the best behavior (possibly N-1 if there's a bug in the latest stable, but that won't be the average case)."_ So, put simply, use the latest NDK and a platform version <= your minSdkVersion.

Comment: Couldn't have said it better myself ;)

Comment: @Michael why we choose a platform version <= your minSdkVersion ?  typo?

Comment: @Poor: No, not a typo. Consider the quote in my first comment, i.e. that a platform version of X specifies that your library can only be used on devices running API level X or later. So at most, X should be the same as your minSdkVersion. But you can set it to something _lower_ than that, if you want to.